# Can I use map2dbg with 64 bit Delphi executables?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I am currently using map2dbg to create a .dbg file from my Delphi .map files. This works beautifully for 32 bit executables. For 64 bit executables the call to map2dbg.exe appears to succeed, but the resulting .dbg file does not appear to be useful. When I view stack traces in Process Explorer, they have no symbol names.

Should I even expect map2dbg to work in 64 bit? And if not, is there an alternative that I can use?

Comment: Sounds like it's working for this guy: http://capnbry.net/blog/?p=18

Comment: @500-InternalServerError That post dates from 2010. The 64 bit in that post must be just a 64 bit OS running a 32 bit Delphi process under the WOW64 emulator.

Comment: I guess you're right - sorry to get your hopes up.

Comment: I don't think so. From what I can find, map2dbg was updated to work with map files created by Delphi versions up to 2009. XE and certainly XE2 are not mentioned. The last commit to the source seems to have been done in 2009. Question remains whether there are significant differences between 32/64 bit map files. It wouldn't surprise me, but can't find anything as yet.

Comment: @marjan map2dbg works fine with 32 bit xe2

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes I know, the map file structure probably still is the same for 32 bit exe's

Comment: can you try tds2pdb (see below) and accept it as answer?

Comment: @André In due course I will. But I have to get to a suitable point.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I've made a small research and it seems that map2dbg can in fact be used for 64bit executables made in Delphi XE2. The only point is you should modify WORD in the produced DBG file at offset 4 from $8664 to $014C.

Yes, this looks like a nonsense, because this means to change Machine field in DBG header from AMD64 to X86, but this really results in a DBG file correctly loading in both WinDbg and Process Explorer.

I've made a patched version of map2dbg version 1.3, so it automatically writes $14c into DBG. Here is the archive: http://yadi.sk/d/kbVFCGyI2gQzM

UPDATE:
DBG files made with the patched version of map2dbg are accepted by both Process Explorer and WinDbg, and the symbols from these DBGs are correctly linked with the corresponding addresses in the executable, but wrong stack frames are displayed.

The reason is in DBGHELP library. As can be seen from its disassembly, it only loads the DBG files made for X86 or Alpha processors (Machine field values $14c and $184). But if we manually change the Machine field in a DBG file from AMD64 to X86, then DBGHELP will treat the executable as a 32-bit module (so PDATA segment from the executable won't be used during the stack unwind), and incorrect stack frames will be shown by the debuggers.

I've patched both x86 and x64 versions of DBGHELP installed with WinSDK for Win8. The patched versions allow for loading DBG files with AMD64 Machine field ($8664), so the stack frames as displayed as expected. These versions are available in this archive: http://yadi.sk/d/7ZDLv2ed2gRGo

So, we now have two different approaches to use the symbols from 64-bit executables compiled with Delphi XE2:

1. Simple way: use the patched map2dbg to produce "fake-x86" DBGs, which can be loaded into WinDbg and Process Explorer, so the symbol addresses will be shown, but the debuggers won't be able to display the stack frames.
2. "Hardcore" way: use the patched dbghelp.dll, with the support of AMD64 DBG files. With this version of DBGHELP, WinDbg and Process Explorer can unwind the stack frames.

ONE MORE UPDATE:
[cv2pdb](https://github.com/rainers/cv2pdb) tool can now convert DBG files created with map2dbg into PDBs. Both 32-bit and 64-bit executables are supported.

[Here's](https://yadi.sk/d/lAobtdXl3TxDh3) a compiled version of the latest sources of cv2pdb.

Comment: Ooh, I'm going to try that out right away! Sounds very promising!

Comment: OK, so I tried it out. It does indeed produce .dbg files that are successfully loaded by Process Explorer. However, the stack traces that Process Explorer emits are incorrect. They have symbols from my executable, but they are clearly not the right symbols. I'm seeing stack traces which say function 1 was called by function 2 and I know that function 2 does not call function 1. I wonder what else is needed.

Comment: I've tested a couple of DBGs in WinDbg, and the symbols were correctly assigned with their addresses.

I think the reason why we cannot see the correct stack info is Delphi uses some not standard stack frames (as compared to MS VC). I'm going to play a bit with different calling conventions, perhaps if Delphi funcs/procs are declared as cdecl or stdcall, they would be displayed as expected.

Comment: Unfortunately, non-default calling conventions do not improve the stack frame info.
It seems that if a DBG file is marked as X86, DBGHELP refuses to use the function info from PDATA segment when it makes stack unwind :(
I'm going to figure out why DBGHELP don't load the original DBG (with AMD64 machine word).

Comment: I appreciate your efforts here. I don't understand what you say about calling conventions. There only is one on x64.

Comment: You are right, all the Delphi calling conventions on x64 are translated into stdcall. I've never checked this before, and I thought there were some differences.

Comment: As for the DBGHELP, I've disassembed the DLL, and from the code it appears that a DBG file is considered to be malformed, if it's not marked as belonging to x86 or Alpha platforms (machine values 0x14c and 0x184).
If we intentionally put 0x14c into a DBG for a x64 module, then DBGHELP loads the symbols from the file, and assigns the correct addresses to these symbols, but when it unwinds the stack, it treats this module as 32-bit, that's why we get strange stack frames in Process Explorer.

Comment: Ok, it's possible to patch DBGHELP so it won't refuse to load DBG files with 0x8664 machine word, and it even would unwind the stack as expected - only two bytes should be changed for this. But there are so many differently compiled versions of DBGHELP, so I cannot simply make an universal patcher for it. I took a DBGHELP version shipped with Win7 x64, patched it, and uploaded it here: [link]http://www.sendspace.com/file/mm76mf

Comment: OK, that's the ticket! Now my stack traces look good, and I'm using plain vanilla map2dbg. Could you possibly update the answer with the new details. Specifically that the problem is in dbghelp.dll rather than map2dbg. And then I'll be delighted to accept the answer. Hopefully this can be useful to other people too.

Comment: Wonderful. I accept with extreme gratitude. By the way, how did you go about working out where in dbghelp to modify?

Comment: I've modified the project from http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11132/Walking-the-callstack article so it called a function from my DLL compiled in Delphi. And then I've debugged the project in MSVC to find out the location in dbghelp library where it decides not to load my DBG file.
There were two such places - in cbFindDbg and in ReadHeader functions.

Comment: Patched Map2DBg and cv2pdb works!. I can see the D10.1 stacktrace in Visual Studio as well.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, *.dbg support is deprecated (note: not even used or loaded!) in newer versions of Microsoft products (windbg, process explorer, visual studio etc).
So even if it creates a valid .dbg file, it will never be used... :-(

My biggest wish is to be able to create a .pdb file! So if anyone can get the specs for it?!
(it is a closed MS format?)
Because, to be even worse, the newest Intel VTune/Threading profiler also does not use .dbg files anymore, so I REALLY WANT A DELPHI TO PDB CONVERTER! (sorry for shouting)

I have tried several things, but no success yet.
That's why I created my own stack viewer and minidump viewer, which uses Delphi debug symbols (.map, .jdbg etc):
http://code.google.com/p/asmprofiler/wiki/ProcessStackViewer
http://andremussche.blogspot.com/2011/03/minidump-reader-for-delphi.html

Note: I haven't tested my stuff on 64bit Delphi apps yet... So it probably won't work, but you can try it anyway...

Comment: Process explorer supports .dbg files

Answer (score 1):

Just for your information: I found a PDB writer
https://github.com/jbevain/cecil/blob/master/symbols/pdb/Mono.Cecil.Pdb/PdbWriter.cs

It's part of the Mono Cecil library (open source .net implementation). 
I hope it can modified to read Delphi .map files too...
(not tested yet)

Comment: Sounds promising. One wonders if PDB files are the same for .net as they are for native code.

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information, I made a Proof of Concept dll for dbghelp.dll, so
it can also read Delphi .map files.
It is some kind of proxy dll: it has the same exports of the real dll, but
they are all forwarded to the real/original dll. 3 symbol functions are
implemented with a Delphi (jclDebug.pas) lookup:
https://plus.google.com/u/0/110131086673878874356/posts/4rmyQM5kVW7 
https://plus.google.com/u/0/110131086673878874356/posts/TSJRqFJR3WZ

Only 32bit for now. ProcesExplorer runs only in 64bit in a 64bit Windows, but 
ProcesHacker also has a 32bit version. When I have some more time I can maybe
improve it further... or try it yourself in the mean time! In 64bit mode you
cannot use "ASM JMP PToProc" but something like "ASM JMP qword ptr [rel p]".

Answer (score 0):

I made some modifications (actually commented the exceptions :-) ) to tds2pdb.
Now it also works for Delphi .tds files, both 32bit and 64bit!
See my G+ post:
https://plus.google.com/u/0/110131086673878874356/posts/eJBKC16e5f6

Note: only ProcesExlorer did not show the full stack of my 64bit test program, ProcesHacker and WinDbg show the full stack though.

Comment: I had a go with this but it looks like it needs a lot more polish. The pdb creation threw up huge numbers of errors. And not being able to strip the TDS info from a 64 bit executable is a bit of a killer.